# Why jQuery("html body div table") returns null, whereas jQuery("html body div") not?

Tags: jquery

```
For the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/MhBTy/
```

Why jQuery("html body div table") returns null and, of course when I check the length of the object, it is zero. However, jQuery("html body div") returns the correct thing I am after. I am sure that "table" is exist in the html source code, but want to know why it returns null? thanks.

Comment: are you sure? 
have you tried this? 
`$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('table length: ' + jQuery("html body div table").length);
  });`

Comment: A ctrl+f in the html doesn't find a table for me. So that's why.

Comment: You should find the "table" in line 1047.

Comment: There is a reason fiddle-only questions are not allowed. Post the code here instead of bypassing the restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine : their is nothing to change in it

```
  alert(jQuery("html body div table ").html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M2sDY/

You forgot to choose jQuery option from left hand side panel

[image]

Comment: I notice that "onLoad" has been applied. Why do we need to apply this? if not applied, why it returns null? Many thanks.

Comment: u have not selected jquery option from left hand side pannel